# bash script to open a terminal tab error gnome-terminal

Tags: bash, xubuntu

I made this script and when i execute it I got the following error

```
#!/bin/bash
# shell script that launchs all commands lines i need


gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=DEV-e 'cd /home/user/path/'
```

Error is

> line 5: gnome-terminal: command not found

got a Xubuntu Xenial

Comment: Run `which gnome-terminal`, what's the ouput?

Comment: How do you execute the script? From where? Is `gnome-terminal` installed? What is the output of `type -a gnome-terminal`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: thanks, I had just a terminal installed but not gnome s one.
please answer to install gnome terminal and i accept!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to make a

> sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal

and thats it.
Thanks